# IPMI data for power supply missing

Tags: ipmi, power-supply-unit

I have 3 **Supermicro AS-1042G-TF** servers and on one there is no data shown for power supply, JAVA application for MAC shows an empty window as do IPMIView apps for iOS and Android, on Android there is a message: *"cannot detect slave address"*.

[image]

I tried:

- unplugging the machine
- resetting BMC via IPMIView iOS app
- resetting IPMI to factory defaults with IPMICFG (**-fd** and then **-fde** options)

but nothing changes...

Is it a hardware fault or maybe some jumper on motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check which power supply you have installed and if it is PMBus capable.  Typically has a P in the model number.  You might also check the FRU tab.